# Getting xcconfig configuration file name from Xcode Run Script

Tags: ios, xcode

My project settings:

[image]

My Run Script:

[image]

But this is not I expected because it only return `Configuration` name instead of `Configuration File` name (I have a xcconfig file called `BetaDebug` for `Debug` configuration). Is there a way to get the xcconfig file name in Xcode Run Script shell?